# How/when should I use v-layout in Vuetify 3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I don't understand when/where/why to use the `v-layout` component in Vuetify 3.

I see, for example, that in [the docs for the app-bar component](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/app-bars/) they have [an example that uses `v-layout`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/app-bars/#density) ([GitHub code](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/docs/src/examples/v-app-bar/prop-density.vue)), but its behavior/effect is confusing: if I run the example CodePen and remove the `v-layout` tags, the `app-bar` component extends to the edge of the page.  I don't understand how/why the `v-layout` is limiting the `app-bar`.

Before:

[image]

After removing `v-layout`:

[image]

The official docs don't really talk about what it's for.  The closest thing to a clue that I get is this comment on [this page](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/application-layout/#application-layout):

> In the following examples, v-app has been replaced by v-layout. This is because v-app defaults to a minimum height of 100dvh. In your own application you would always use v-app for the root layout.

But `v-app` itself doesn't seem to have a clear explanation in the Vuetify 3 docs, I just know that it's supposed to be the topmost tag in a Vuetify app.

So is `v-layout` just something that certain Vuetify components (like the app bar and navigation drawer) use to determine where they should show up on the screen?  Like, it defines the extent of the Vuetify app for those app bar and nav drawer components?

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find the answer if you look at the difference between the docs for `v-layout` in Vuetify 2 and Vuetify 3.

[**In the vuetify 2 documentation** you **see a lot of props**](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-layout/), which are used to align, center, etc., so the `v-layout` is used for flexbox.
[**On the vuetify 3** documentation you **see almost nothing**](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-layout/).

And, if you try, indeed **the props don't exist anymore**, look at [this script](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNqNkMtuwjAQRX/F9YZWIraAqguUIrrrH3RBWIRkaN36JdtJhVD+vWMnVOGxYOe5M75n5m6O9M1a1jZAlzQPoKwsA6wKTUjeZqW16ZmKyuhQCg1ukJIoy4NpAqmMbJT+b2CrFu3KmV8yy3l83ujMzzs5P7mdkCicM6PSr5Tz0apY+soJG4iH0PQbC2WNC+RIHOxJR/bOKDLBKydxnOC+2gei/Cd5jROPk3eQ0pAP42T9MHmKgN4SzeiU9m6ZKi379kZjVMfoUgwNX9AlSUrUkBLrgn6FYP2S86rW+K0GKVrHNASureJrHOOu0UEoyGqj1gu2YM+YiA9jmYFX2Q7j8uDQpKDTESaI/eEO1DCZCPOeMEgY+M5HxJU1R14LLnOga3Dg7r3o4tv4qovW1WWR3hW6w7yl0D/+IurKp5g3pyXvOnnOXtjs1s3JLVptI7Gb0rQoolNIdPsHgOsGmA==) with vuetify 2, we use the props column like this:

```
<v-layout column>
  <div>row 1</div>
  <div>row 2</div>
</v-layout>
```

And if you watch [this code](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNqlkE1OwzAQha8yeBOQmli0rKpQlR03YNF0kSZTCPhPthNUVbk7YydFacuiEjv7zcz7Zt7myF6MyboW2ZLlHqURpcdVoQDyLi2Nic/4qbTyZaPQjlIURXnQrYdKi1aq3wKV6qZbWf0NjzkPzz8q8/NKzk9uJyQJ58ygDCvlfLIqfV1lG+PBoW+HjRtptPVwBIt76GFvtYSErkxCO9C+ynmQ7h2eQ8d98opCaHjTVtR3yUMADJZkxmZscEtlabJPpxVFdQwuxVhwBVtCVIJGlPAv2If3xi05r2pFYzWKprOZQs+VkXxNbdy2yjcS01rL9SJbZE+UiPNTOUMn0x3F5dCSScFmE4xv9ocbUGNnJMwHwihR4DsXEFfWnHgd2tSiqtGivfWii7HpVRelq8sCvS9UT3mLRn25i6grF2PenJb818nRLDhtA7CfsbgnkeMA2/4Af30GZQ==) with vuetify 3, you can see we have a row.
So, i think, `v-layout` is obsolete now, we keep him because migration from 2 to 3 is easier.
I have personally on vuetify 2 never see or use `v-layout`.

Answer (score 1):

The v-layout component is used to **create responsive layouts**. It provides a flexible grid system that allows you to arrange and align your content in a structured manner.

**The v-layout component is part of the Grid system in Vuetify**, which is based on the CSS Grid specification. It helps you divide your page into a grid of columns and rows, making it easier to create responsive designs that adapt to different screen sizes and orientations.

With v-layout, you can specify the number of columns each item should occupy and control their alignment within the grid. It supports various alignment options such as start, end, center, stretch, and space between items. You can also define the order of items within the layout using the order property.

Here's a simple example of using v-layout to create a responsive grid layout with two columns:

```
<template>
  <v-layout row>
    <v-flex xs6>
      <!-- Content for the first column -->
    </v-flex>
    <v-flex xs6>
      <!-- Content for the second column -->
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
</template>
```

In this example, the v-layout component is used with the row property to create a horizontal layout. Inside the layout, we have two v-flex components representing the columns. The xs6 property on each v-flex specifies that each column should occupy 6 out of 12 available columns on extra-small screens. Vuetify's grid system is based on a 12-column layout, so xs6 means each column takes half of the available width.

**By using v-layout and its related components, you can easily create responsive and customizable layouts in Vuetify.**

Comment: The other answer says `v-layout` is deprecated and gives a compelling argument for it, but I'm not sure how to reconcile that with your answer; in fact, your example uses a prop that isn't listed in the API docs for `v-layout` in Vuetify 3.  What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

In Vuetify 3 the VLayout becomes VRow and VFlex becomes VCol, please, use the correct tag even if the old one is still available

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/grids/#v-row

Their behavior depends on many things, like if it is inside a VConteiner... VMain... what props you are using in its parent elements...

In your case, VLayout it is inside a VCard and that's wraps VAppBar width to the VCard width and when you remove, VAppBar width extends to the next parent grid layout width, VApp.